# Can Exchange pull messages from a POP3 catchall mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

can it be possible to have the following topology for exchange:

1. have a catch all mailbox hosted on the internet
2. configure exchange (within the internal network) to pop mail from there and route it into user mailbox as per rule

i believe something like this should be possible, would like some confirmation
and/or any implementation tips/pitfalls.

Comment: You *can* do this, but why would you ***want to***? Wouldn't it be better to deliver directly to Exchange and use Exchange rules to handle the catchall?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that topology is possible with Exchange but you need a "POP3 connector" to download and distribute the emails from the catch-all mailbox. 
The "Small Business Server" versions of Exchange already come with a POP3 connector but if you're not using SBS you can use any of the available 3rd party connectors. Try POPcon - that's one that just works.

Comment: thanks claus, just one thing to throw into the mix... would adding an edge role in a dmz be possible (and would it add any value) or something like POPCon pro do the job ?

Comment: An Edge Transport server would do nothing for this situation.